# How to create a custom slot class in Pharo

Tags: pharo

I don't understand how to create my own subclass of `Slot` and use it in Pharo. The problem is that it looks like the slot-handling code requires me to implement #size and #index but I have no idea what to put in there.

The use case is the definition of a class that represents a configuration. A user can specify part of the configuration and relies on default values to specify the rest. To do that, I want to define a slot class that has (1) a default value (2) a dictionary. The idea is that when reading the slot, the dictionary is searched for a key that has the slot's name. If a key is found, then the value of the slot is the value found in the dictionary. If no key is found in the dictionary, the value of the slot is the default value.

Comment: Just so that people reading this question are aware. According to Marcus Denker slots are not ready for end-users yet: https://www.mail-archive.com/pharo-dev@lists.pharo.org/msg23786.html

Answer (score 1):

Things are moving forward in Pharo 4 including Slots. Here is an example implemented by Jan to demonstrate what you can do with Slots:

https://pharoweekly.wordpress.com/2015/02/21/example-implementation-of-associations-with-slots-in-pharo-4-0/